# Linux kernel severe boot-time increase; how to investigate on it?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

Starting from kernel 4.5, boot-time increased from 900ms (4.4.44) to 2.1s (4.9.5).

I want to fix, or at least help developers by opening a proper bug report but I don't know which information provide in order to fill an useful report.

So, how investigate on this kernel boot-time issue?

*PS*: I am on a Dell XPS 9343 (Broadwell) with Arch Linux x86_64 and Gnome.
*PS2*: Actually I have LTS kernel (4.4.44) and -ck (4.9.5) installed both in my system and I choose them from the systemd-boot menu and times above-reported are taken from the `systemd-analyze` command, *kernel* entry.
*PS3*: As I notice (and measure) increased boot-time, I noticed the same on poweroff but in this case I do not know how to measure it.

**EDIT1**: requested outputs for kernel 4.9

```
[mattia@arch-xps ~]$ systemd-analyze blame
          2.356s dev-sda3.device
          1.648s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-88E7\x2d8ACB.service
          1.646s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e2a87acb\x2d9e12\x2d4501\x2dbb
          1.346s tlp.service
          1.324s systemd-journald.service
          1.307s systemd-udev-trigger.service
          1.306s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.296s colord.service
          1.005s systemd-journal-flush.service
           947ms user@1000.service
           944ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           854ms accounts-daemon.service
           564ms systemd-rfkill.service
           244ms org.cups.cupsd.service
           163ms packagekit.service
            89ms NetworkManager.service
            86ms bluetooth.service
            75ms systemd-logind.service
            53ms upower.service
            53ms user@120.service
            49ms polkit.service
            43ms systemd-udevd.service
            38ms wpa_supplicant.service
            36ms udisks2.service
            28ms systemd-sysctl.service
            25ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            22ms boot.mount
            20ms systemd-random-seed.service
            19ms gdm.service
            16ms geoclue.service
            16ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
            14ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            13ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            11ms dev-sda2.swap
            11ms dev-mqueue.mount
            10ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            10ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
             8ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
             7ms home.mount
             6ms systemd-update-utmp.service
             6ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             6ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             5ms dev-hugepages.mount
             5ms rtkit-daemon.service
             3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             3ms tmp.mount

[mattia@arch-xps ~]$ systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @5.282s
└─gdm.service @5.258s +19ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @5.244s +6ms
    └─nss-user-lookup.target @5.288s
```

**EDIT2**: requested output for kernel 4.4

```
[mattia@arch-xps ~]$ systemd-analyze blame
          1.356s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e2a87acb\x2d9e12\x2d4501\x2dbb
          1.355s systemd-rfkill.service
           895ms user@1000.service
           861ms tlp.service
           474ms dev-sda3.device
           379ms systemd-localed.service
           310ms systemd-hostnamed.service
           310ms systemd-timedated.service
           255ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           188ms org.cups.cupsd.service
           146ms systemd-journald.service
           112ms packagekit.service
            60ms bluetooth.service
            60ms NetworkManager.service
            59ms accounts-daemon.service
            58ms upower.service
            49ms systemd-udevd.service
            48ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-88E7\x2d8ACB.service
            37ms user@120.service
            36ms polkit.service
            33ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            25ms systemd-journal-flush.service
            24ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            22ms udisks2.service
            17ms gdm.service
            16ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            16ms dev-sda2.swap
            16ms boot.mount
            15ms colord.service
            15ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            13ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            13ms dev-hugepages.mount
            13ms geoclue.service
            13ms systemd-sysctl.service
            13ms home.mount
            10ms systemd-logind.service
             9ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             8ms wpa_supplicant.service
             8ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
             7ms systemd-random-seed.service
             7ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
             5ms systemd-update-utmp.service
             5ms rtkit-daemon.service
             4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             4ms tmp.mount
             3ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
             3ms dev-mqueue.mount
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount

[mattia@arch-xps ~]$ systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2.555s
└─gdm.service @2.536s +17ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @2.525s +4ms
    └─nss-user-lookup.target @2.559s
```

**EDIT3**: no, they have the same size approx.

```
[mattia@arch-xps ~]$ ls /boot/
total 62M
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4.0K Dec 10 17:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4.0K Dec 14 17:49 EFI
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Jan 11 16:39 grub
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May 14  2016 loader
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  21M Jan 20 15:40 initramfs-linux-ck-fallback.img
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 5.7M Jan 20 15:40 initramfs-linux-ck.img
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  20M Jan 17 18:01 initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 5.6M Jan 17 18:01 initramfs-linux-lts.img
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 961K Nov 15 18:43 intel-ucode.img
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4.6M Jan 20 15:38 vmlinuz-linux-ck
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4.3M Jan 15 15:05 vmlinuz-linux-lts
```

**EDIT4**: a try with kernel from official repo (see sixth-seventh comments), give a significant different boot-time of 1.3s but still higher than kernel 4.4

```
[mattia@arch-xps ~]$ systemd-analyze blame
          1.979s dev-sda3.device
          1.369s systemd-journald.service
          1.347s colord.service
           871ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           868ms user@1000.service
           868ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           793ms systemd-udevd.service
           782ms tlp.service
           508ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           503ms user@120.service
           473ms wpa_supplicant.service
           177ms org.cups.cupsd.service
           110ms packagekit.service
            85ms NetworkManager.service
            85ms systemd-journal-flush.service
            66ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e2a87acb\x2d9e12\x2d4501\x2dbb
            49ms upower.service
            47ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-88E7\x2d8ACB.service
            44ms accounts-daemon.service
            28ms bluetooth.service
            27ms polkit.service
            24ms gdm.service
            22ms udisks2.service
            18ms systemd-rfkill.service
            16ms systemd-logind.service
            15ms geoclue.service
            13ms boot.mount
            13ms dev-hugepages.mount
            12ms dev-mqueue.mount
            11ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            11ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
            11ms systemd-sysctl.service
            10ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             9ms dev-sda2.swap
             9ms kmod-static-nodes.service
             8ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             7ms home.mount
             7ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
             7ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
             6ms systemd-update-utmp.service
             5ms tmp.mount
             5ms systemd-random-seed.service
             4ms rtkit-daemon.service
             4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             2ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
[mattia@arch-xps ~]$ systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @4.604s
└─gdm.service @4.397s +24ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @4.379s +8ms
    └─nss-user-lookup.target @4.425s
```

Comment: Please post the output of `systemd-analize blame` and `systemd-analize critical-chain`.

Comment: @nwildner, added **BUT** notice that issue is kernel

Comment: (I added outputs both for kernel 4.4 and 4.9)

Comment: I think the problem is in initrd, it is loaded with the kernel at the startup, and become bigger and bigger year after year in the major distributions, maybe it is growing to much. Can you post the size of the initrd for the new and the old kernel ? And if the problem is with the kernel, i think it is related to the compilation and not too the new version.

Comment: @mattia.b89, You should have same configuration on kernel 4.4 and kernel 4.9 when you made boot time comparison. Default kernel is 4.4 LTS. Where did you get kernel 4.9?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini, added sizes in OP. I will try the latest kernel in official repo in order to test your compilation-related issue idea

Comment: @supriady, I get linux-ck kernel from AUR. As I have above-written in the sixth comment, I will test a kernel (the one from official Arch repo) with a configuration more similar to LTS one (it comes from official repo, too)

Comment: OP updated with new results

Comment: @mattia.b89.You want to do fair comparison.You can use kernel 4.4 config to kernel 4.9 and build own kernel 4.9 from kernel source code.You should know sometimes new kernel version loaded some new features/new module.Maybe you can use diff command to check any differences between /boot/config-4.4.x and /boot/config-4.9.x.

Comment: @supriady, I don't like a such _attempts_ procedure... I think `systemd-analyze` brings useful information but I am not able to interpret them. e.g. `systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-88E7\x2d8ACB.service` entry grows up from 48ms to 1.648s!